# Advanced SQL Query Design Help (Duplicates across two tables, multiple fields, possible exclusions based on one field)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, named:

1) item

2) bankitem

Item has the following fields:

ID, CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID2, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute, Equip, X, Y

Bankitem has the following fields:

ID, CharID, Name, ItemID, Count, Type, ID1, ID2, ID3, Color, Effect1, Effect2, Effect3, LifeSpan, Attribute

**Objective:**

I would like to pull an individual listing (i.e., not just a count) from across these two tables that have the following fields in common: Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, and ID3 so that I can scan the listing and investigate any duplicate entries, prior to deleting one of them. Every other field could potentially be different based on the nature of how the database is updated.

Also, sometimes there may certain records that are okay to have duplicates (again, based on the nature of how the database is used). Is there a way to build into the script to exclude duplicates (based on the above fields) if the field "Name" equals one of the exclusions I could set up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am relatively new to SQL queries - I know what I want to do, but am really lost on how to get to the next step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2,ID3 FROM item
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2,ID3 FROM bankitem
```

Or use UNION if you don't  want duplicates.If you dont want duplicates in the table just use an unique index on that column.

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count(*) no_of_records FROM item 
UNION 
SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count(*) no_of_records FROM bankitem 
GROUP BY Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3 HAVING count(*) > 1)as x 
WHERE x.Name != 'RedPotion'
```

Or

```
WHERE x.Name NOT IN('blah1','blah2')
```

Comment: Thanks. The list generated is far too long, is there any way to build in a list of "Name" values that could be excluded (multiple values if possible, eg BluePotion, RedPotion)

I've also been playing with this SQL query as a summary (not individual listing)

SELECT
    Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count(*) no_of_records
FROM item
UNION
SELECT
    Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count(*) no_of_records
FROM bankitem
GROUP BY Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3
HAVING count(*) > 1;

Where could I insert a list of exclusions (would this work?):  AND (item.Name != 'RedPotion' OR bankitem.Name != 'RedPotion')

Comment: @user3025251 SELECT * FROM(SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count() no_of_records FROM item UNION SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count() no_of_records FROM bankitem GROUP BY Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3 HAVING count(*) > 1)as x WHERE x.Name != 'RedPotion'

Comment: Thanks @Mihai - I really appreciate your help. When I try to run the command (copied and pasted verbatim), it says I have an error in the syntax near ') no_of_records FROM item UNION SELECT Name, ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3, count() no_o' at line 1. Also if I wanted to add multiple exclusions, would I just add commas, e.g. x.Name !='RedPotion','BluePotion'.

Comment: @user3025251 Consider accepting the answer,if you like.CLick under the arrows.

Comment: Hi @Mihai...sorry to bother you again.  Is there a way to implement a new feature into this command whereby the query only returns results where the CharID IS NOT NULL? The query would still return results based on duplicate ItemID, ID1, ID2, ID3. I would need this so the CharID could be different (e.g., character1 has a CharID of 1234 and character2 has a CharID of 9999 yet they both have the same duplicate item).

Comment: @user3025251 Add to both SELECTS CharID and after the WHERE blah add AND CharID IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Hi @Mihai - When I add CharID to both SELECTS and CharID IS NOT NULL it is only pulling duplicate records based on the same CharID e.g., Char#1234 has two items that have the same Name, ItemID, ID1/2/3. I would like the query to pull duplicates (based on Name, ItemID, ID1/2/3) but those items could have unique CharID, e.g. Char#1234 has 1 of the duplicates and Char#9999 has the other duplicate. For context purposes, the database is a game where items are tracked by IDs but many characters - so duplicate items could be on multiple characters with different CharIDs. Any advice?

Comment: @user3025251 I think the group by messes your results.Somebody else might manage it,but I have difficulty imagining exactly what you want.Consider creating a fiddle or editing your post with sample data to clarify. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1